# CreateProcessWithLogon Error requires elevation

Tags: windows, winapi

all
I am using CreateProcessWithLogon method to installing softwares for non autherized users to installing software, it was working fine for windows XP users, but same application shows the error as follows in windows 7 machine.

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(0x80004005): the requested operation requires elevation

please any one suggest me any idea to fix it.

i am using the code as follows

```
Private Const LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY As Integer = &H2
Private Const NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS As Integer = &H20
Private Const CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE As Integer = &H4000000
Private Const CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE As Integer = &H10
Private Const CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP As Integer = &H200
Private Const LOGON_WITH_PROFILE As Integer = &H1
Private Const LOGON_WITH_PROFILE1 As Integer = 0


    Dim siStartup As STARTUPINFO
    Dim piProcess As PROCESS_INFORMATION
    Dim intReturn As Integer
    Dim bResult As Boolean = False
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim sFile, sArg As String

    IMP_USER_NAME = AppSettings("UserName")
    IMP_PASS_WORD = AppSettings("Password")
    IMP_DOMAIN_NAME = AppSettings("Domain")

    Try

        If sApplication.EndsWith(".msi") Then
            sApplication = sApplication & " " & """ALLUSERS=1"""
            sArg = "msiexec.exe /i """ & sApplication & """"
            sFile = vbNullString
        Else
            If bToExecute = False Then
                sArg = vbNullString
                sFile = sApplication
            Else
                sArg = "cmd /c """ & sApplication & """"
                sFile = vbNullString
            End If
        End If

        siStartup.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(siStartup)
        siStartup.dwFlags = 0


        intReturn = CreateProcessWithLogon(IMP_USER_NAME, IMP_DOMAIN_NAME, IMP_PASS_WORD, LOGON_WITH_PROFILE, sFile, sArg, _
                        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS Or CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE Or CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE Or CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP, _
                        IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, siStartup, piProcess)
```

Thanks,
Senthil

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem. The operation requires elevation. I suggest that you first read up and learn about UAC, then come back with any further questions.

Answer (score 1):

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2010/02/01/why-can-t-i-elevate-my-application-to-run-as-administrator-while-using-createprocesswithlogonw.aspx : you need an intermediate process that execute `ShellExec()` to elevate the priveleges of an application called with `CreateProcessWithLogon`

Alternativeley, you can call `cmd /c cd <targetDir>&<targetDrive>:&<execName>` with CreateProcessWithLogon to avoid creating that intermediate process.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the reason is that you use `LOGON_WITH_PROFILE` flag. In the "Remark" part of the [CreateProcessWithLogonW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431%28VS.85%29.aspx) documentation you can read following

> By default, CreateProcessWithLogonW
>   does not load the specified user
>   profile into the HKEY_USERS registry
>   key. This means that access to
>   information in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER
>   registry key may not produce results
>   that are consistent with a normal
>   interactive logon. It is your
>   responsibility to load the user
>   registry hive into HKEY_USERS before
>   calling CreateProcessWithLogonW, by
>   using LOGON_WITH_PROFILE, or by
>   calling the LoadUserProfile function.

So I recommend you to try the same code without `LOGON_WITH_PROFILE` flag. If you will see that it was the problem and you do need to use the flag you should use [LoadUserProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762281%28VS.85%29.aspx) function and [UnloadUserProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762282%28VS.85%29.aspx) in your code.

Comment: That's not it, UAC is stopping him.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I am not sure whether you are right or not. in the documentation to CreateProcessAsUser (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429(v=VS.85).aspx) you can read "CreateProcessWithLogonW requires no special privileges, but the specified user account must be allowed to log on interactively. Generally, it is best to use CreateProcessWithLogonW to create a process with alternate credentials.". So it seems that `CreateProcessWithLogonW` shold work independ on UAC. But **senthil** can easy test it.